# LG Ultrafine 5k -- right half is a slightly different color from left

Tags: macos, display, color

New refurbished model # 27MD5KA. I have attached a photo (apologies for the reflections).

[image]

There is a line down the exact middle of the screen, directly below the webcam. On the right side of the screen the panel is slightly lighter than the left side (or the left is slightly darker -- I'm not sure which is the 'correct' color/brightness). You can tell very clearly in Intellij IDEA in the default darcula color scheme. It's harder to tell on light backgrounds.

I'm guessing this has something to do with the dual display port 1.2 streams that the monitor uses.

Is there any way to color correct this on macOS?

Comment: That’s a fault  of the monitor.  You need to return it for refund/replacement

Comment: Thanks @Allan. Is there a chance it's the MacBook? (pro, 2018)

Comment: No.  The channels only send display data.  There’s no reason one channel would send info in a different contrast/brightness. If it were analog, there might be a possibility, but the issue is your monitor

Comment: @Allan -- because of iCruiser's comment below, I tried a different scaled resolution -- every scaled resolution other than default fixes the problem. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

I've been having this issue for quite some time. Usually, a reboot would make it go away, but recently it has become much more persistent. One workaround I found was to turn on Night Shift but set it all the way to the "Less Warm" side.

It looks like an issue with macOS. I have filed a bug report to Apple.

Update: Apple fixed this issue on macOS Mojave 10.14.6 GM (18G84).

Comment: There are multiple reports of this problem with this particular monitor. The fact that there’s a transition where the panels meet is also suspicious.

Comment: I enabled/disabled True Tone and Night Shift multiple times and now the issue has temporarily gone away. Also, this problem does not occur on any other resolution settings other than the native 5120x2880, so I still think it's a software issue associated with macOS. That said, can you share where you found other reports of this particular problem?

Comment: Just to say that I've noticed this issue using a MacBook Pro 16" connected to 2x LG UltraFine displays. The issue presents itself on 1 of the UF displays, and interestingly the MBP display itself. I can see a difference in colour from one side to the other, and a transition in the middle. So this seems to be a software issue as others have suggested as it's affecting the MBP screen also, rather than a hardware issue wit he UF displays.